# The Basics of Parse Blocks in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, closures, objective-c-blocks

I'm having a little issue on understanding how exactly blocks work.

```
for x in self.activerestaurantIDArray
{
let namelabel = x.0
self.activenameArray.append(namelabel)

let distancelabel = x.1
self.activedistanceArray.append(distancelabel)

let imageFile = x.2 
imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

if error == nil {
let realimage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
self.activeimageArray.append(realimage!)                          
}

println(self.activenameArray)
println(self.activedistanceArray)
println(self.activeimageArray)

})                         
}
```

In the code above, I am appending information to an array from the tuple (named: `activerestaurantIDArray`) so that I will get separate arrays of name, distance and image. As for the image, I can only retrieve a PFFile from parse so I will have to transform the file into a UIImage.

However, when I do this, the appends for the activeImageArray is in effect only when the `println()` is within the Block (`imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`).

If I were to `println(self.activeimageArray)` at any place outside of the box, the array will turn out nil. I am not really sure why that happens or how I should go about ensuring that the appended values carry out beyond the Block{}. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Closures (also known as yes, blocks) are pieces of code that can be called later, they are essentially functions.

What you are doing in `imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` is to download the data, and when the data is downloaded, `imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` will call your *block*, passing you the contents of the thing it just downloaded.

It is done this way because downloading must take place in a separate thread. Otherwise your main thread will freeze, and not only will it cause annoyances for the user, but after 5 seconds of non-responsiveness, the OS will kill your app. `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` spawns a different thread for the download operation, and then it lets you know by calling your block. This allows you to download anything without "freezing" or "hanging" your app.

So `imageData`, when outside the block, is nil because you are trying to use it before the block has completed the download operation. Your code will never run slower than a download operation, so you must use the block to implement the code you want to use when an operation finishes downloading, in this case, setting the imageData.

Edit to add, this is not exclusive to Parse. Almost any framework that can freeze your UI will do those operations and implement the notifications using blocks. It's still possible to be notified by using delegates, but ever since blocks were introduces in Objective-C, people have been moving away from that pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have a question though. If I were to use the data from the arrays, is it advisable to write all those tasks under the block?

Comment: Only if the arrays depend on the block. Ultimately it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: In this particular case, I want to load table cells with data from the arrays I've gathered here. So in order to populate the cells, the function would have to be called within the block?

Comment: Declare your array as a property. Fill it up in the block. Afterwards call reloadData(), and wire your logic to use that array for the table contents.